Error seleccion de paises en direcciones checkout - prestashop
Estoy tratando de seleccionar un país que me debe mostrar sus provincias según elección, el problema es que el "preview" del navegador me muestra: "ss11277"
No sé de dónde proviene, pero al seleccionar cualquier país se quita todo y me salta eso, alguna solución al respecto?
Es prestashop version 1.7.5
